# Lower triangle correlation heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I'm trying to produce a `lower triangle` `heatmap` of pairwise correlations in `R`.

Here's the data:

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(6*10),ncol=6,nrow=10)
colnames(mat) <- c("s.-.+.1","s.-.+.2","s.-.+.3","s.+.-.1","s.+.-.2","s.+.-.3")
```

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
getUpperTri <- function(cor.mat){
  cor.mat[lower.tri(cor.mat)] <- NA
  return(cor.mat)
}

reorderCormat <- function(cor.mat){
  dist.mat <- as.dist((1-cor.mat)/2)
  hc <- hclust(dist.mat)
  cor.mat <-cor.mat[hc$order,hc$order]
}
cor.df <- reshape2::melt(getUpperTri(reorderCormat(cor(mat))),na.rm=TRUE,value.name="correlation",varnames=c("sample1","sample2"))
```

And the `ggplot` `heatmap` code is:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(cor.mat.df,aes(sample2,sample1,fill=correlation))+geom_tile(color="white")+scale_fill_gradient2(low="blue",high="red",mid="white",midpoint=0,limit=c(-1,1),space="Lab",name="Pearson\nCorrelation")+theme_bw()+theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,vjust=1,size=10,hjust=1))+coord_fixed()+labs(x="",y="")
```

Which gives me:

[image]

So the colored elements are scattered all over rather than being confined to the lower triangle.

Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: It seems to work.  I think you just used the wrong variable in the ggplot function: cor.mat.df should be cor.df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I reproduced your script and this is my plot[image: plot]

Just change

```
ggplot(cor.mat.df ,aes(sample2, sample1, fill=correlation))+
  geom_tile(color="white")+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="blue", high="red", mid="white", midpoint=0, limit=c(-1,1), space="Lab", name="Pearson\nCorrelation")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,vjust=1,size=10,hjust=1))+
  coord_fixed()+
  labs(x="",y="")
```

by

```
ggplot(cor.df, aes(sample2, sample1, fill=correlation))+
  geom_tile(color="white")+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="blue", high="red", mid="white", midpoint=0, limit=c(-1,1), space="Lab", name="Pearson\nCorrelation")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, vjust=1, size=10, hjust=1))+
  coord_fixed()+
  labs(x="",y="")
```

My sessionInfo:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Colombia.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Colombia.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Colombia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                     
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Colombia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.8      digest_0.6.11    assertthat_0.1   grid_3.3.2       plyr_1.8.4      
 [6] gtable_0.2.0     magrittr_1.5     scales_0.4.1     stringi_1.1.2    reshape2_1.4.2  
[11] lazyeval_0.2.0   labeling_0.3     tools_3.3.2      stringr_1.1.0    munsell_0.4.3   
[16] colorspace_1.3-2 tibble_1.2
```